# apache2: Syntax error Cannot load mod_deflate.so into server: undefined symbol: inflate

Tags: apache, module, configuration, httpd.conf

Activation of modul makes this error:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload

bad apache2 configuration!
apache2: Syntax error on line 11 of /etc/apache2apache2.conf:\
Syntax error on line 91 of /etc/apache2/modules.conf:\
Cannot load lib/apache2/mod_deflate.so into server:\
/usr/lib/apache2/mod_deflate.so: undefined symbol: inflate
```

Here is a part from apache2.conf:

```
LoadModule authn_file_module lib/apache2/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module lib/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module lib/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module lib/apache2/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module lib/apache2/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module lib/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module lib/apache2/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module lib/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule macro_module lib/apache2/mod_macro.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module lib/apache2/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module lib/apache2/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module lib/apache2/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module lib/apache2/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module lib/apache2/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module lib/apache2/mod_env.so
LoadModule expires_module lib/apache2/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module lib/apache2/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module lib/apache2/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module lib/apache2/mod_version.so
LoadModule remoteip_module lib/apache2/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule proxy_module lib/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module lib/apache2/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule unixd_module lib/apache2/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module lib/apache2/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module lib/apache2/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dir_module lib/apache2/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module lib/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module lib/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule deflate_module lib/apache2/mod_deflate.so
```

Here output of ldd mod_deflate.so:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe4361000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f65a16d8000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055c73817f000)
```

I use debian jessie
uname -a:

```
Linux dev 4.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.11-1~bpo8+1 (2016-12-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

greeting
Andre

Comment: **It's about apache 2.4.25**

Comment: what is the result of command "ls -la /usr/lib/apache2/mod_deflate.so" ?